# How to use an image as a button for another image

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok so what im trying to understand is how to click on luigi and have marios picture also move without clicking mario. later on i am going to add lives under mario and clicking mario will reset the lives but for now i just need to get down the concept of somehow linking mario to luigis clicking

```html
<img id="Luigi" src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/facebook/000/783/973/b32.jpg" onmousedown="this.src='https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/28d5b169-09dd-40a2-8a73-a38cc7a74dbb/d8h77tb-b4729c49-baa4-4fd3-86e5-36f08b0b5a3f.jpg?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcLzI4ZDViMTY5LTA5ZGQtNDBhMi04YTczLWEzOGNjN2E3NGRiYlwvZDhoNzd0Yi1iNDcyOWM0OS1iYWE0LTRmZDMtODZlNS0zNmYwOGIwYjVhM2YuanBnIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.BkesqSJkbe9cC59as-DveaiLpYMkNF2gxS7oQts23OY'"
  onmouseup="this.src='https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/facebook/000/783/973/b32.jpg'" width="300px">

<img id="Mario" src="https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/8cbabdda-80b4-4926-ac0f-1b71cc9d64dd/de9ijk6-c2b4cb6b-d901-47b2-94a8-f342216a1284.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcLzhjYmFiZGRhLTgwYjQtNDkyNi1hYzBmLTFiNzFjYzlkNjRkZFwvZGU5aWprNi1jMmI0Y2I2Yi1kOTAxLTQ3YjItOTRhOC1mMzQyMjE2YTEyODQucG5nIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.sUBkcsXhf36u8MAni87shNLupcdABpwpDxRf_ymk3HY"
  onmousedown="src='data:image/jpeg;base64,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'"
  onmouseup="src='https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/8cbabdda-80b4-4926-ac0f-1b71cc9d64dd/de9ijk6-c2b4cb6b-d901-47b2-94a8-f342216a1284.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcLzhjYmFiZGRhLTgwYjQtNDkyNi1hYzBmLTFiNzFjYzlkNjRkZFwvZGU5aWprNi1jMmI0Y2I2Yi1kOTAxLTQ3YjItOTRhOC1mMzQyMjE2YTEyODQucG5nIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.sUBkcsXhf36u8MAni87shNLupcdABpwpDxRf_ymk3HY'"
  width="300">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+OR+CSS+change+image+"on click"+OR+onclick+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reference the element itself using the `this` keyword and modify its `src` property:

```html
<img id="Luigi" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" onmousedown = "this.src = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176'" onmouseup = "this.src = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1'">
```

It's recommended not to use inline event listeners. In this case, you can try using custom data attributes to store the desired source of the image on mousedown and mouseup, then use JavaScript to add an event listener that assigns that attribute value to the `src` property:

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
images.forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    this.src = this.dataset.mousedown;
  })
  e.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    this.src = this.dataset.mouseup;
  })
})
```

```html
<img id="Luigi" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" data-mousedown="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176" data-mouseup="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
```

Comment: Please delegate instead of looping eventhandlers.

Comment: like add 'this' keyword into the same onmousedown with the second set of images?

Comment: like my image one does change on mousedown mouseup. but i just dont understand how to click on image set one and have it also change image set 2

Comment: @KrazyL Please update your question and post relevant information about what you mean by image set 2. You can click `[<>]` and post a [mcve] as I already suggested

Comment: wait like you mean like put actual image links?

Comment: @KrazyL have you seen the first example? You have to assign the source to the elements' `src` property via `this.src = 'imagesource'`

Comment: @spectric and that lets my mario change when i click on juigi

Comment: @Spectric yeah im trying and i think im just not meant to code. but i gotta figure this out for school because we are working on a project that i have to do exactly what i am trying to do here to head on to the next steps. and im not able to ask the teacher for assistance otherwise i probably wouldnt have found this site.